# Need a way to access files of a device through accesspoint

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ftp, file-sharing

I have a Chinese made portable fundus camera bought through a 3rd party. It boast of file access through wifi. To that end, it broadcasts an access point to connect to. I don't have any manual for the device and I can't find the makers of the device as well(looks exactly shanghai topview pfc). The device has sd card that I want to access through wireless interface.
I figured out the password to the said access point and am able to connect to it.
How do I access the files of the device?
I am using windows 8.1.
I tried to connect through running \192.168.1.1 on the run window as well as the browser but to no avail.
I enabled network and sharing on windows and I tried ipv4 preferred ip assigned to it (192.168.1.3) I was shown explorer with no files or folders even though there are files on the device.
Pinging ipv4 address works fine.

Comment: Most likely FTP, but it could be anything, really.

Comment: If you can connect to it, maybe a http page? It would help to have more information than "chinese medical device"